# Cannot query ConversationEntry records for Enhanced Whatsapp Channel

Tags: query, digital-engagement, messagingsession, whatsapp

Our org is migrating from Standard Whatsapp Channel to Enhanced Whatsapp Channel. We have already adapted our Einstein Bot and tested the channel succesfully. Messaging Sessions work as expected.

However, we have not been able to find single messages from this Enhanced Channel by querying the ConversationEntry object on WorkBench. Only records from the standard bot are available.

Anybody could provide some knowledge on why this happens?
Are enhanced conversation messages saved differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enhanced Messaging channels use off-Core storage and this is why ConversationEntry records cannot be accessed via SOQL. In order to fetch this data, you must use Core Connect API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_conversation_entries.htm

Hope this is of help! ;)

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the help. I was able to succesfully query my Enhanced Channel conversations. However, I see Messaging Component choices are saved as messageText: null. Is there anyway to query the value (Title) of the Messaging Component choice selected by the user?